# Multiple post requests on an event triggered AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I am doing a real time app, and in one part of the application, some data is posted to the server when an event is triggered, this is then updated to the db. The problem is each browser connection instance is posting the same data, resulting in multiple db updates from the instances. I can't seem to see a way of figuring this out. Kindly assist.

Comment: Please post a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by sending post results from a single client who matched some criteria, and now it works fine.